# Descargar .TXT desde HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Como hago para que al dar click sobre el boton probrar ejecute el script y me descargue la información, Gracias.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function mostrar() {
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];
var miArray3 = ["TaT","Pan","Aut","Caf"];
var mostrar = "";
for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
 mostrar += j + " "+miArray3[i];
}
}
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = mostrar;
}
</script>

<button onclick="mostrar();">Probar</button>
<div id="download('Desgarga', 'resultado')"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hola, haber si entiendo lo que pides. Tratas de generar un archivo **.txt** con `JavaScript` y posteriormente cuando hagas uso del evento `onclick` de `javascript` puedas ejecutar la funcion `mostrar()` y lo que generes dentro de ella es lo que deseas que esté como contenido del `.txt` ?

Comment: ¿Que es lo que has intentado y por qué no funciona? ¿Por qué  el id del div tiene el texto de como si quisieras llamar una función y enviar 2 parametros?

Comment: `download('Desgarga', 'resultado')` esto por que ? yo creo que no debe ser asi: que hace esa funcion ?

Comment: Si dejo solo    <div id="resultado"></div>    me imprime el resultado de mostrar(), lo que intento hacer es que cuando haga click en Probar ejecute mostrar() y no me imprima sino que me descargue

Comment: te descargue que ?

Comment: Me descargue la el resultado de la función

Comment: ¿Has buscado en el sitio? Si no recuerdo mal, ya hay una pregunta igual a ésta. Voy a ver si la encuentro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Función descargar archivo sacada de https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542499/1423096 por [Ludivic Feltz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2576706/ludovic-feltz)

```js
function mostrar() {
  var miArray = [10, 20, 40, 65];
  var miArray2 = [15, 26, 44, 71];
  var miArray3 = ["TaT", "Pan", "Aut", "Caf"];
  var mostrar = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = miArray[i]; j <= miArray2[i]; j++) {
      mostrar += j + " " + miArray3[i];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = mostrar;
  saveDoc("archivo.txt", mostrar);

}

saveDoc = function(filename, data) {
  var blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'text/csv'
  });
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
    elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    elem.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.click();
    document.body.removeChild(elem);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="mostrar();">Probar</button>
  <div id="resultado"></div>

</body>
```

Para compatibilidad con Internet Explorer primero se busca si existe la función [msSaveOrOpenBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx).

Si no existe se asume un navegador mas compatible con estándares y se procede a crear un enlace que tenga la representación binaria del contenido del archivo, se lo agrega al documento y se le hace click al enlace, lo cual dispara un descargar archivo.

Para esto se utilizan las funciones

- [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) para crear un elemento tipo enlace
- [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) esta función crea una cadena de texto que representa un archivo o en este caso el contenido de un archivo.
- [document.body.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) para agregar el elemento al body del documento
- [document.body.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) para remover el elemento del documento una vez hecho el "click"

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco cómo funciona la función o qué es lo que hace exactamente?

Comment: Muy buen aporte

Answer (score 1):

si solo quieres mostrar el contenido en ese `div` lo unico que debes hacer es darle un id y enviarle el valor

```
   <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function mostrar() {
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];
var miArray3 = ["TaT","Pan","Aut","Caf"];
var mostrar = "";
for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
 mostrar += j + " "+miArray3[i];
}
}
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = mostrar;
}
</script>

<button onclick="mostrar();">Probar</button>
//aqui pones el id
<div id="resultado"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hola srJJ lo que necesito en vez de imprimir con id, es mas bien que me descargue en texto el resultado

Comment: se lo descargue aun archivo tipo `txt` ??

Comment: si con el atributo download

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function mostrar() {
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];
var miArray3 = ["TaT","Pan","Aut","Caf"];
var mostrar = "";
for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
 mostrar += j + " "+miArray3[i];
}
}
//document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = mostrar;

  var contenidoDeArchivo = mostrar;
var elem = document.getElementById('descargar');

elem.download = "archivo.txt";
elem.href = "data:application/octet-stream," 
                     + encodeURIComponent(contenidoDeArchivo);



}
</script>

<a id="descargar" onclick="mostrar();">Probar</a>
<div id="download('Desgarga', 'resultado')"></div>

</body>
```