# Descargar blob desde IE8?

Tags: javascript, jszip

estoy intentando guardar un archivo Zip con IE8 pero no me es posible ya que estoy usando la librería JSZip.js en conjunto con la FileSaver.js, pero la libreria FilesSaver.js me da un error "El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'createElementNS'". Esto es segun lei por que no permite guardar un archivo blob.

Esto es lo que estoy usando y en chrome me funciona perfecto.

```
var Promise = window.Promise;
if (!Promise) {
    Promise = JSZip.external.Promise;
}

function urlToPromise(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
             if(err) {
               reject(err);
           } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

  function CreaZip(){

     var zip = new JSZip();


         var url = "/xxxxx/DownloadFile.do?TIP_Documento=xxxx&TIP_Archivo=xxxxx&COD_Tribunal=xxxxx&CRR_IdDocumento=xxxx&CRR_IdTramite=xxxx"; 
         /* var filename = url.replace(/.*\//g, ""); */
         var filename = "test.pdf";
         zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(url), {binary:true});


 zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
 .then(function callback(blob) {

     // see FileSaver.js
     saveAs(blob, "example.zip");
 });
 return false;

 }
```

Alguien conoce algún método que permita guardar un archivo blob en IE8?, que lo único que he visto es lo referente a descargar txt o html.

Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: tendrías que usar [msSaveOrOpenBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx) fijate la función `saveDoc` de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188850/81450

Comment: Gracias alo Malbarez, no tenia como responderte directamente asi que lo hago por aca. Echare un vistazo a ver como implementarlo en conjunto con el blob generado al comprimirse.
Saludos!