# ¿Se pude crear un archivo XML con JavaScript y guardarlo en disco?

Tags: javascript, html, array, xml

Llevo varios días buscando una posible solución a este problema, tengo un formulario con múltiples campos hecho en `HTML`, en el cual al hacer `click` en el botón de `SUBMIT` me toma los valores de cada uno de sus inputs y lo mete en un `array`

```
0: "2"
1: "105920808"
2: "Carlos Briceño"
3: "212135"
4: "cbrice@femw.com"
5: "3213asdasdas"
6: "cmbriceno@gmail.com"
7: "87047866"
8: "87047866"
9: "1"
10: "55"
11: "8"
12: "Urbanizacion Las Lomas"
13: "Alto de Guadalupe, Urbanización las Lomas"
14: "324131"
15: "pass1 "
16: "444444444444"
17: "1231"
18: "321"
19: "32"
20: "1"
21: "1"
22: "98"
23: "Carlos"
24: "0"
25: "cmbriceno@gmail.com"
26: "24402969"
27: "87047866"
28: "0"
29: "0"
30: "0"
31: ""
32: ""
33: "1231132"
34: "Cambiar AE"
35: "02"
36: "CRC"
37: "01"
38: "565.28"
39: "01"
40: (9) ["1", "123456", "1", "I", "100000", "Linea 1", "", "", "08"]
41: (9) ["1", "10101", "1", "Alc", "20000", "linea 2 ", "10", "", "08"]
42: "This is a test"
43: "118000"
44: ""
45: ""
46: ""
47: ""
48: ""
49: "118000"
50: ""
51: ""
52: "2000"
53: "118000"
54: "116000"
55: ""
56: ""
57: "133340"
```

Lo que necesito es que al dar `click` en `submit` se genere un archivo `XML` y se guarde en disco con una estructura específica, llevo rato averiguando pero parece no haber mucha información al respecto. El resultado esperado sería algo parecido a esto.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
  <person first-name="eric" middle-initial="H" last-name="jung">
    <address street="321 south st" city="denver" state="co" country="usa"/>
    <address street="123 main st" city="arlington" state="ma" country="usa"/>
  </person>

  <person first-name="jed" last-name="brown">
    <address street="321 north st" city="atlanta" state="ga" country="usa"/>
    <address street="123 west st" city="seattle" state="wa" country="usa"/>
    <address street="321 south avenue" city="denver" state="co" country="usa"/>
  </person>
</people>
```

Me he documentado con esta web https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/How_to_create_a_DOM_tree  . En la cual explican muy bien como generar una estructura XML sin, embargo no logro que se me guarde en disco un archivo

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
  <person first-name="eric" middle-initial="H" last-name="jung">
    <address street="321 south st" city="denver" state="co" country="usa"/>
    <address street="123 main st" city="arlington" state="ma" country="usa"/>
  </person>

  <person first-name="jed" last-name="brown">
    <address street="321 north st" city="atlanta" state="ga" country="usa"/>
    <address street="123 west st" city="seattle" state="wa" country="usa"/>
    <address street="321 south avenue" city="denver" state="co" country="usa"/>
  </person>
</people>

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y agrega la nueva información en la misma. Sería mas útil que agregues el código que genera el `XML`

Comment: Sería un XML simple como ese, perdon por el formato de la pregunta de arriba, no se como orgarnizarlo. He visto en varios sitios como W3schools y developer Mozilla pero aun no veo como hacerlo

Comment: Ok amigo ya la edito

Comment: Ya la he editado Marcos, ocuparía algo parecido a lo que esta en el ejemplo, solo que no se como hacer para que al presionar submit se me guarde en un archivo. Lo ideal sería llenar el archivo XML con la informacion de mi formulario o en defecto con la del array. Pero sería de gran ayuda que me guiaras para poder guardar un archivo como ese

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Descargar .TXT desde HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188839/descargar-txt-desde-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple es crear dinámicamente un elemento `a` al cual le indicamos en el `href` el contenido del `XML`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function downloadFile() {

  let filename = 'people.xml';
  let text = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <people> <person first-name="eric" middle-initial="H" last-name="jung"> <address street="321 south st" city="denver" state="co" country="usa"/> <address street="123 main st" city="arlington" state="ma" country="usa"/> </person> <person first-name="jed" last-name="brown"> <address street="321 north st" city="atlanta" state="ga" country="usa"/> <address street="123 west st" city="seattle" state="wa" country="usa"/> <address street="321 south avenue" city="denver" state="co" country="usa"/> </person> </people>';

  let element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="downloadFile()">
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

### Referencias:

- [Respuesta relacionada SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/3791844)

Comment: Broo, muchisimas gracias, aceptaría tu pregunta pero no tengo suficiente reputación, te lo agradezco un monton

Comment: Aceptar respuestas te da reputación. Ademas es tú pregunta y solo vos la podes "aceptar". Votar la puede votar cualquier usuario registrado. Revisa [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tenes alguna duda

Comment: Aceptada, aun no me manejo muy bien aquí, aceptarla es lo menos que puedo hacer, gracias de verdad!!!

Comment: En caso de que llenar la estructura xml con los datos del array sabrías como?

Comment: Seria bueno que primero lo intentes hacer vos. Si no te sale, entonces podes crear una nueva pregunta incluyendo lo que hiciste y el problema que se te presento.